# ViewPager is calling getItem method multiple times?

Tags: android

`ViewPager` is calling `getItem()` method multiple items on First time

```java
public class DemoViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


    public DemoViewPager(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm,BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    //    layerDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        Log.d("Demo ","Position Clicked in View Pager : "+position);

        DemoFragment2 demoFragment2 = new DemoFragment2();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        position = position + 1;
        bundle.putString("Position",String.valueOf(position));
        demoFragment2.setArguments(bundle);
        return  demoFragment2;

    }
}
```

Comment: And the question is ... ?

Comment: Your `getCount()` returns 10. So use conditions like `if(position == 0)` and so on.

Comment: I am using Single Fragment with different Values , but Values are  getting overrided in the fragment

Answer (score 2):

A ViewPager will always initialize the adjacent fragments according to its `offscreen page limit`.

The minimum offscreen page limit is 1, so if you initialize the adapter at `0`, you'll always get `0` and `1` to be initialized. When you go to `1`, then it'll also create `2`.

So fragments are initialized ahead of time so that you can swipe to them.

Comment: How can i use single Fragment in View Pager with Different data passing each time to fragment for network calls ?

Comment: You can pass arguments to fragments before they are created